# Same transformation which different parameters in the job

Tags: pentaho

I have a transformation with a parameter that I need to change 5 times.
I want to create a job that execute this transformation 5 times changing my parameter value inside each transformation.

[image]

like:

Transformation Q1 - Parameter = 1

Transformation Q2 - Parameter = 2
...

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use a transformation to generate the parameter values, and pass the rows to fill up the parameter value in the second transformation:
[image: Second option for job]

[image: Properties for CommonTrans]

[image: Configuration to pass the parameter value]

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with passing parameter in the 'Transformation Executor' step in Job.

You can found an sample from [Here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1ZGezEjjl5vk0pcbDdcBafcQh_z7oxKGJ?usp=sharing). See the log after run my Job.

[image]